# What is the origin of the phrase "देशकालवस्तुपरिच्छेदशून्यम्"?

Tags: philosophy, advaita, vedanta, brahman

Phrase "देशकालवस्तुपरिच्छेदशून्यम्" is used in many Advaita vedanta lectures. In which scripture it has its origin?

Comment: Rel: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/51955/29449